# Происхождение фамилии Чайковская

Tags: имена-собственные

Девичья фамилия моей мамы - Чайковская. Однофамилица или дальная родственница великого композитора. Но вот трактовок фамилии мне попадалось множество: то от "чайки", то от "чая", то от "чайки" - старинного корабля. А что говорят по этому поводу лингвисты?

Answer (score 1):

Лингвисты вообще говоря не занимаются подобными трактовками, поскольку одна и та же фамилия может происходить от разных основ или разных значений одной основы.
Конкретно Петр Ильич носил фамилию по названию украинского села Чайка, откуда были его предки.